# Floating Facebook Like Box For prestashop

Tags: prestashop, facebook-likebox

I am triying to install a floating likebox in prestashop website

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery(".abtlikebox").hover(function() {jQuery(this).stop().animate({right: "0"}, "medium");}, function() {jQuery(this).stop().animate({right: "-250"}, "medium");}, 500);});
 /*]]>*/
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 .abtlikebox{background: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mMtB2ANqowQ/T6es-PuSR2I/AAAAAAAAAjM/LDamrUnMJJc/s320/fb1-right.png") no-repeat scroll left center transparent !important; float: right;height: 270px;padding: 0 5px 0 46px;width: 245px;z-index:  99999;position:fixed;right:-250px;top:20%;}
.abtlikebox div{ padding: 0; margin-right:-8px; border:4px solid  #3b5998; background:#fafafa;}
.abtlikebox span{bottom: 4px;font: 8px "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;position: absolute;right: 6px;text-align: right;z-index: 99999;}
 .abtlikebox span a{color: gray;text-decoration:none;}
 .abtlikebox span a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
}
</style>
 <div class="abtlikebox" style="">
     <div>
     <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fallbloggingtips&amp;width=245&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=white&amp;connections=9&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=270" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: white; overflow: hidden; height: 270px; width: 245px;background:#fafafa;"></iframe><span></span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The problem that all website break when i add jquery in head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to use this code without jquery.min.js? 
I think that jquery are included in prestashop

Comment: Your code works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/8jmv3v4s/. If you are using HTTP in your page, please replace HTTP by HTTPS in iframe `src` attribute.

Comment: What version of Prestashop are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.1.7 with  https